# How can I specify the position of an admin bar item added with $wp_admin_bar->add_menu() or add_node()?

Tags: admin-bar

I want to add a link to my site in the admin bar, and make that link the leftmost item in the admin bar. I can add a link with this in a plugin function:

```
$wp_admin_bar->add_menu( array(
        'id' => 'my-link',
        'title' => __('MySite'),
        'href' => site_url() 
    ) );
```

But I'd like to make it the leftmost link in the admin bar, i.e. all the way in the top left corner. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I am correct these are the default positions:

- wp_admin_bar_wp_menu - 10
- wp_admin_bar_my_sites_menu - 20
- wp_admin_bar_site_menu - 30
- wp_admin_bar_updates_menu - 40
- wp_admin_bar_comments_menu - 60
- wp_admin_bar_new_content_menu - 70
- wp_admin_bar_edit_menu - 80

small code snippet from what I use:
 `add_action('admin_bar_menu', 'your_function_name', 10);`

The `10` should bring it to the most left side in the adminbar.

At moment we are at WP version 3.8 and it still work like a charm.

*Added example:*

```
function add_item($admin_bar)  {
$args = array(
    'id'        => 'your-link', // Must be a unique name
    'title'     => 'Yoursite', // Label for this item
    'href'      =>__ ('your_site_url'),
    'meta'  => array(
        'target'=> '_blank', // Opens the link with a new tab
        'title' => __('Yoursite'), // Text will be shown on hovering
    ),
);
$admin_bar->add_menu( $args);
}
add_action('admin_bar_menu', 'add_item', 10); // 10 = Position on the admin bar
```

Comment: doesn't work for me

Comment: note that they are in chunks of 10 for a reason - I wanted an item to appear right after the "edit post" link, so I used `81`

Answer (score 2):

I attempted Charles solution but with no success.  I did find out though that you can specify whether which side of the admin bar your content is added.

Using

```
add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'yourfunctionname' );
```

will add your new content to the left side of the admin bar before the default content.

Using

```
add_action( 'wp_before_admin_bar_render', 'yourfunctionname' );
```

will add your new content to the right side of the admin bar after the default content.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to completely reorganize the admin bar you must use `WP_Admin_Bar()`.

Example:

```
function reorder_admin_bar() {
    global $wp_admin_bar;

    // The desired order of identifiers (items)
    $IDs_sequence = array(
        'wp-logo',
        'site-name',
        'new-content',
        'edit'
    );

    // Get an array of all the toolbar items on the current
    // page
    $nodes = $wp_admin_bar->get_nodes();

    // Perform recognized identifiers
    foreach ( $IDs_sequence as $id ) {
        if ( ! isset($nodes[$id]) ) continue;

        // This will cause the identifier to act as the last
        // menu item
        $wp_admin_bar->remove_node($id);
        $wp_admin_bar->add_node($nodes[$id]);

        // Remove the identifier from the list of nodes
        unset($nodes[$id]);
    }

    // Unknown identifiers will be moved to appear after known
    // identifiers
    foreach ( $nodes as $id => &$obj ) {
        // There is no need to organize unknown children
        // identifiers (sub items)
        if ( ! empty($obj->parent) ) continue;

        // This will cause the identifier to act as the last
        // menu item
        $wp_admin_bar->remove_node($id);
        $wp_admin_bar->add_node($obj);
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_before_admin_bar_render', 'reorder_admin_bar');
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Admin_Bar