# How to Add a Link to the Drop-Down User Menu in the Admin Bar?

Tags: php, admin-menu, admin-bar

I need to add a link to the drop-down user menu in the admin bar.  Is there a hook or function for this?

[image: WP admin bar user drop-down menu]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [$wp_admin_bar->add_node( $args )](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Admin_Bar/add_node).

Below is a tested working example.

```
function wpse_add_toolbar_edit($wp_admin_bar) { 
    $wp_admin_bar->add_node( array(
        'id'        => 'mylink',
        'title' => 'My New Link',
        'href' => 'mailto:support@domain.com',
        'parent' => 'user-actions'
    ) );
}

add_action('admin_bar_menu', 'wpse_add_toolbar_edit', 999);
```

Note: The `parent` param adds the link to an existing ID.  If you need to find the correct ID to add your new link to you can `var_dump($wp_admin_bar);` and look through the output for the correct ID.

Comment: Is there a way to position my link between "Edit My Profile" and the "Log Out" link?

Comment: That is more complicated.  Have a look at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/how-can-i-specify-the-position-of-an-admin-bar-item-added-with-wp-admin-bar-ad maybe the last answer will help.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps to add link between logout and edit my profile.
1. remove the default logout node

```
$wp_admin_bar->remove_node( 'logout' );
```

2.add the link that you want to put between logout and edit my profile.

```
$wp_admin_bar->add_node([
    'id'        => 'link-id',
    'title' => 'Link Title',
    'href' => get_site_url(null, 'site-path'),
    'parent' => 'user-actions'
]);
```

3. Add the logout node back to the list using:

```
$wp_admin_bar->add_node([
    'id'        => 'logout',
    'title' => 'Log Out',
    'href' => wp_logout_url(),
    'parent' => 'user-actions'
]);
```

Just manipulated the above function in order to insert the link between logout and profile.

Final Code:

```
 add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'adjust_admin_menu_bar_items' , 999);
 function adjust_admin_menu_bar_items ($wp_admin_bar) {
   $user = wp_get_current_user();

   $wp_admin_bar->add_node([
     'id'        => 'link-id',
     'title' => 'Link Title',
     'href' => get_site_url(null, 'site-path'),
     'parent' => 'user-actions'
   ]);

   $wp_admin_bar->add_node([
     'id'        => 'logout',
     'title' => 'Log Out',
     'href' => wp_logout_url(),
     'parent' => 'user-actions'
   ]);
 }
```

Hope this will help. :)